# PHP Clear File Content With Link

Tags: php

I wanna clear the content of a file called txt.txt by clicking a link. I've looked through the site and Googled up a storm but can't figure it out. I know there are threads here that talk about it but nothing explain exactly how to do it. Thank you :o)

Comment: Your question in unclear. You want to click a hyperlink from your webpage that will clear the contents of `txt.txt` hosted in your application?

Comment: I have a form on index,php that writes to txt.txt using PHP. On the index.php, I want to have a link that will clear the contents of txt.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know routing in your app, try this logic)

```
<a href="/clearfile.php">clearfile</a>

//in clearfile.php

<?php
file_put_contents('', 'txt.txt');
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
die;
```

Comment: This worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Clean with:

```
  $fn=fopen('txt.txt','w'); 
  fclose($fn);
```

Delete with:

```
  @unlink('txt.txt');
```

This will clear the file and all its content (without deleting it)

Comment: I know the commands to clear the file, just not how to turn it into a link that will do it. I did it years ago but don't remember how.

Comment: in another file as the colleague dns_project told u.